# I installed Zerigo, but there is no Zerigo dashboard in my Heroku admin panel

Tags: heroku, dns

I installed Zerigo DNS Basic using command line.

```
$ heroku addons:add zerigo_dns:basic

cjmac:~ cj$ idt
cjmac:idt2 cj$ heroku addons:add zerigo_dns:basic
Adding zerigo_dns:basic to idt... done, v91 (free)
```

When I go to  my add-ons page for Zerigo (`.../addons/zerigo_dns:basic`), there is a link to "Add or remove a domain in the Custom Domains Add-on Dashboard →."

That link takes me to `.../addons/custom_domains`.  There is no dashboard, only a link to Heroku documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com).

What happened to the dashboard?  It is there for my other sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom domains on the Heroku Dashboard at: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/:your_app_name/settings. They will then show up on your Zerigo add-ons page.

I'm opening an internal issue to fix the Zerigo documentation and redirect. Thanks for bringing it to our attention!